# How to hide the preview area visible after Find Usages action?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like the bar on the bottom with **Found usages** to cover whole screen width i.e. to hide area with `Select usage to preview` text on it. Could you tell me how to obtain that?

[image: unwanted_area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hover over `>>` symbol on left side panel of that tool window (or make the tool window taller for the moment) and then disable the "Preview Usages" option:

[image]